# Authentication Issues (KRB5\GSS)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

We are looking to migrate some systems away from MSSQL. We have our first few environments built and currently using LDAP, which is OK but has a good number of flaws.

I followed this link to setup Kreberos\GSS for the most part: https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/windows-active-directory-postgresql-gssapi-kerberos-authentication

Off the bat I got the below error when trying to connect:

```
psql: error: SSPI continuation error: The specified target is unknown or unreachable
```

I believe the SPN is setup properly:

```
setspn -S POSTGRES/server.domain.local domain\service_account
```

I suspect something is wrong in the keytab file, as there is an extra "" between the server FQDN and domain:

```
Keytab name: FILE:/opt/pgsql/server.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   5 postgres@server.domain.local\@DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

Server side error:

```
2020-12-28 18:37:43.820 EST [64534] user@DOMAIN.LOCAL@postgres FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "user@DOMAIN.LOCAL" 
2020-12-28 18:37:43.820 EST [64534] user@DOMAIN.LOCAL@postgres DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 gss"
```

I'd appreciate any feedback and thank you!